# How to validate missing inputs, operational statement, and format of date in UNIX?

Tags: shell, unix

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

a=`date -d $1 '+m/%d/%Y'`
b=`date -d $2 '+m/%d/%Y'`

#checking missing inputs
if [ -z "$a" ] || [ -z "$b" ];
then 
   echo "Missing inputs"
   exit 255
fi 

date: invalid date '+m/%d/%Y'`
date: invalid date '+m/%d/%Y'`
Missing inputs

#checking date format
if [ $a != '+m/%d/%Y' ] || [ $b != '+m/%d/%Y' ];
then
   echo "INVALID DATE"
   exit 255
fi 

#checking a >= b
if [ $a -ge $b ];
then
   echo "a should less than b"
   exit 255
fi
```

When this execute, if I inputted the right format of date, it gives me the output of "INVALID DATE" which in the 2nd condition.

If I tried not to provide any inputs, it gives me an error of:
date: invalid date '+m/%d/%Y' `date: invalid date '+m/%d/%Y'`
Missing inputs

If only one input is provided:
date: invalid date '+m/%d/%Y'`
Missing inputs

If I tried to input:
5/4/1999 6/4/1999
It gives me an error of INVALID DATE.

I can't give a right validation of needed. Anyone has some ideas on how to optimize or fix this?

Comment: I'd expect to see an `a: command not found` error -- variable assignment can not have spaces around the `=`

Comment: bash cannot validate date formats with the string equality operator `!=`

Comment: @glennjackman removed the space but still got the same bug/error

Comment: If no inputs are provided, what should your program do? Abort? Use some default date?

Comment: @glennjackman It will just exit and show the echo message.

Comment: Well, you're **using** $1 and $2 before you validate that they exist. Move a=... and b=...

Comment: @glennjackman can you clarify what should I move?

Comment: `a` is only empty if `$1` is empty, so why are you trying to execute `date` on an empty argument if `$1` is empty?

Comment: Somewhat ironically, if you were correctly quoting `$1` and `$2` in those two commands, you wouldn't get an error, but instead today's date for both `a` and `b`. But if your script requires two dates, then you should be checking if `$1` and `$2` are set before trying to use them.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to set values for $1 and $2 not removing the a and b?